# How to justify a very long ciphertext and corresponding plaintext in Latex?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I have a very long ciphertext and corresponding plaintext both are of 680 alphabets without space to print in a latex document. I have not found any way to make justify it in internet. Any Ideas please?

Text is like as follows without any space:

```
RFROSERHUKEITFRIZXHVNVSIRLCJPWGSYVSMGKIOPEBUWCDEZZTVWIGKATEPSUWJPRGYEJPEFUHGCZCZCGNPCJEVZLSIECCCCLRGELWEKKYKOSOWEWCDEVSMBXMAOIOIAPOXVRTOLOSJYQFJCIGGEXCKANVMQRNVEIZCYQFNIJTPZAKYAVELSDOTLPCWTJLXWJBWEMGYANWVSDEOMIFZTKYEPZTRPVVRPUTXVRSPESBVANTGSMEPEYFVDVZVSDATVXIKTWEGVZLFDEWUTJPHITHGDWSMETJXVZNIDKCKAOZVOCIHZRZPYQFGOEFKYHWKAPOWVVSSFISQEFSIFJENQYDTLQDIFKOCWMQVSUTHSRSUSIGGOMPEZZCGOMREOVXYQYLKVIYVERTRUJOEWSGVTQSIFWITDXPVCCFWSKHGOYQYEUDAOJVGCCIXLALRRJEEZRRCYDPGOLSGDLSNAUPBOTTNJXVVRKRLHYEKRLHKOTPWHYETNLWEURZROCIEPWGYOWWHSIAPOMHNAULRIECQXJCITCMPMJHCCTQYIPSSKVVGCWVVDKORCKLKVIHFBGCYRVSQDLSSOTPMHRSYPPZRSUSIQFUNOXVVGCXIGXOKYKCERCELSIBGEXSINQHWVVSCTHPPWCJSTBEGAMBXURELSTOPGIFJAVTSBRLKEXZV
```

Comment: You could consider the following as well: [Stacking text for cryptography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121717/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [seqsplit](http://ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit) package, as explained in [this tex.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/wrapping-long-lines-that-contain-no-spaces).